# Can I repeat unordered list tags for my type of situation?

Tags: list, validation, unordered

I'd just like to ask if this coding method is still valid.

```
<div class="one-third column">
  <ul class="nav-link">
    <li class="button">Going to put code here.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="one-third column">
  <ul class="nav-link">
    <li class="button">Going to put code here.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="one-third column">
  <ul class="nav-link">
    <li class="button">Going to put code here.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see I'm repeating the unordered lists inside of the div class. This is necessary for me because I'm using Skeleton boilerplate and I need them to be in 3 columns, with the unordered lists. 
I tried putting the list items inside the divs, but the validator states you cannot put div tags inside the unordered lists. So I'm asking if this method is still okay for me to use, since this website will be used as a public template. If there's an alternative way I can code this, please let me know. Thank you.